# PUBNUB read unread messages count

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pubnub

I am developing chat application using PUBNUB. I need to get the count of `unread` messages  from PUBNUB.Is it possible?

How can i complete this requirement using PUBNUB.

Please suggest

Comment: Hi @Kichu this is a good common question!  We are working on making this easier for you with [PubNub Blocks](https://www.pubnub.com/products/blocks/) product coming soon.  However for now there is a basic option that will work okay: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30536484/524733 **read this previous post**.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. i all ready saw this post but i didn't get any clear idea :-(

Comment: Is it possible to update the message in pubnub using angular API?

Comment: PubNub Storage and Playback is **Immutable**.
There is no way to update messages.  You need to publish new messages with the modifications you want to be reflected in state.

Comment: Pubnub should provide this kind of feature. I felt the same thing when I created chat application with pubnub then latter on i had to switch on something else

Comment: PubNub is providing this feature. Expect to see announcement in coming months (possibly around November 2016). Until then you can [implement a design pattern that provides a the desired end result](http://pubnub.github.io/pubnub-design-patterns/2015/02/26/Message-Update-Delete.html#_ga=1.217879509.217456567.1459794989).